# how to get the speed of the process in android

Tags: java, android, networking

I know the API "long getUidRxBytes (int uid)",but this interface could not get the network speed with each process. Is there someone who konws a simple way to get the speed of the prcocess.

my english is not very well.

Comment: what do you mean by "speed of the process" ?

Comment: the network speed of process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to measure speed of anything, you need 2 parameters: time and amount.
Here, I assume you are calculating byte/s, you need to measure how many bytes transfered every second. 
Almost time, you will need a algorithm such as

```
totalTimeSpent = 0
bytesSent = 0
do
  beforeSendingTime = getCurrentMilisecond
  send n bytes to desination via network
  bytesSent = bytesSent + n
  afterSendingTime = getCurrentMilisecond
  timeSpent = afterSendingTime - beforeSendingTime
  totalTimeSpent = totalTimeSpent + timeSpent
  say: currentSpeed = n/timeSpent
  say: averageSpeed = bytesSent/totalTimeSpent
loop until no data remaining to send
```

Hope it help, you need to implement that algorithm in your own development language